# Laravel Passport client_credentials

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

Good Day does any one using the method like this one ?
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport#client-credentials-grant-tokens

i try to make registration API that has client_id and client_secret only and i want the return that as access token, refresh token, expire_date  but the return of the 
www.url.com/oauth/token is this

```
{
    "error": "unsupported_grant_type",
    "message": "The authorization grant type is not supported by the authorization server.",
    "hint": "Check the `grant_type` parameter"
}
```

anyone can help me.. ?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old and I don't know if you got it working. Based on your description of the problem, the `grant_type` parameter is likely missing from the request. You need `grant_type`, `client_id`, and `client_secret`. When I omit the parameter I get the same validation error message. If you're using the client credentials grant you need `'grant_type' => 'client_credentials'` if you're using code in the example.